# How to change user without closing applications running, when using RDP on a Windows machine?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, user-accounts, login

The problem I have is that multiple users need to RDP to a machine to check the status of an application that is running. Normally, when users login/logout, the applications will stop and the user will have his own environment. What I need, is that the users can login/logout, while the application will continue running and the newly logged-in user will be able to check the status of it. Something like a shared desktop for different users.

Comment: The application needs to run as a service so that individuals can login with their own credentials and use a UI to view the status of the service, or you need a shared login on that client machine and staff checking the application will only lock the machine when the disconnect, allowing the session and application to continue running. The first method is far superior from a security and design perspective. The second method should only be used if the application is incapable of another method of running.

Comment: @music2myear, Thank you for your answers! I agree that the first is the best solution, but the application I want to run is an application we bought and it's expected to run as a normal UI application. So, we can't convert it to service, to my knowledge. The second option is one we don't want to proceed with. 
Any other options?

Comment: "Something like a shared desktop for different users." - This does not exist in Windows.

Comment: Given that OP found a piece of software that meets their needs but the software description does not match or approach the problem presented in this question, I suggest this question be closed unless it can be edited to better describe the problem, but as there is already a self-solution, I don't think that is likely.